# How to switch between GitHub branches in Google Colab

Tags: git, google-colaboratory

I have cloned a GitHub repository in Google Colab using `!git clone ...` but now I want to switch to another branch I have been working on. Seems like GitHub doesn't provide a unique clone link for different branches and colab doesn't allow `!git checkout ...` commands. Is there any way I can change branches in colab?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, for example:

```
!git clone https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools.git
!cd colabtools && git checkout incoming
```

```
Cloning into 'colabtools'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 125, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (125/125), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (125/125), done.
remote: Total 1580 (delta 58), reused 67 (delta 0), pack-reused 1455
Receiving objects: 100% (1580/1580), 466.90 KiB | 861.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (887/887), done.
Branch 'incoming' set up to track remote branch 'incoming' from 'origin'.
Switched to a new branch 'incoming'
```

Comment: Aha! I was not doing the ``cd ...`` part. Thank you so much for jumping in and answering it quickly!

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use `%` instead of `!` for `cd` command.

```
!git clone https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools.git
%cd colabtools 
!git checkout incoming
```